# How to select as group from array, modify and add to their places again

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I have this list:

```
list_to_modify = [[296.0, 277.0, 1560.0, 361.0],
 [1958.0, 595.0, 2059.0, 674.0],
 [291.0, 573.0, 371.0, 882.0],
 [1957.0, 696.0, 2058.0, 777.0],
 [1959.0, 797.0, 2060.0, 876.0],
 [1964.0, 490.0, 2063.0, 573.0],
 [298.0, 1084.0, 785.0, 1235.0],
 [300.0, 1423.0, 371.0, 1729.0],
 [1631.0, 1614.0, 2067.0, 1728.0],
 [304.0, 1810.0, 790.0, 1961.0],
 [1438.0, 1902.0, 2065.0, 2014.0],
 [1384.0, 2075.0, 1887.0, 2194.0],
 [997.0, 2241.0, 1099.0, 2319.0],
 [1392.0, 2331.0, 2010.0, 2447.0],
 [999.0, 2341.0, 1100.0, 2419.0],
 [997.0, 2441.0, 1100.0, 2519.0],
 [999.0, 2542.0, 1100.0, 2619.0]]
```

I want to select elements if `element[0]` resembles to other `element[0]` in the array. The order is important so I just need to modify the array as chunks. So that it becomes to this:

```
desired_list = [[296.0, 277.0, 1560.0, 361.0],
 [1964.0, 490.0, 2063.0, 573.0],
 [291.0, 573.0, 371.0, 882.0],
 [1958.0, 595.0, 2059.0, 674.0],
 [1957.0, 696.0, 2058.0, 777.0],
 [1959.0, 797.0, 2060.0, 876.0],
 [298.0, 1084.0, 785.0, 1235.0],
 [300.0, 1423.0, 371.0, 1729.0],
 [1631.0, 1614.0, 2067.0, 1728.0],
 [304.0, 1810.0, 790.0, 1961.0],
 [1438.0, 1902.0, 2065.0, 2014.0],
 [1384.0, 2075.0, 1887.0, 2194.0],
 [997.0, 2241.0, 1099.0, 2319.0],
 [1392.0, 2331.0, 2010.0, 2447.0],
 [999.0, 2341.0, 1100.0, 2419.0],
 [997.0, 2441.0, 1100.0, 2519.0],
 [999.0, 2542.0, 1100.0, 2619.0]]
```

I can't use regular sorting here because these are coordinates from image inputs so if I sort this like this:

```
sorted(list_to_modify, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

since not every image is identical, this causes problems. For example I need to take this as a chunk:

```
 chunk = [1958.0, 595.0, 2059.0, 674.0],
 [1957.0, 696.0, 2058.0, 777.0],
 [1959.0, 797.0, 2060.0, 876.0],
 [1964.0, 490.0, 2063.0, 573.0],
```

and sort it by the second item:

```
chunk = sorted(chunk, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

and then plug it into the list again with new indexes. Because the last item is the first item right now. I need to use first item's index in the original list and plug the last item to first item's place (if it's confusing, please look at `desired_list`, you'll understand what I mean).

I've come so far:

```
temporary=[]
dummy_list = [None] * len(ilk)

for x in list_to_modify:
  if list_to_modify.index(x) != 0: #I don't want to touch the first item
    val = x[0]
    first_cond = val - 20
    second_cond = val + 20
  for y in list_to_modify:
    if list_to_modify.index(y) != 0 and y[0]>first_cond and y[0]<second_cond :
      if y in temporary:
        pass
      else:
        temporary.append([list_to_modify.index(y),y])

  temporary= sorted(temporary, key=lambda x:x[1][1])

newlist=[]

for i in temporary:
  if i not in newlist:
    newlist.append(i)
```

And this is the result :/

```
[[5, [1964.0, 490.0, 2063.0, 573.0]],
 [2, [291.0, 573.0, 371.0, 882.0]],
 [1, [1958.0, 595.0, 2059.0, 674.0]],
 [3, [1957.0, 696.0, 2058.0, 777.0]],
 [4, [1959.0, 797.0, 2060.0, 876.0]],
 [6, [298.0, 1084.0, 785.0, 1235.0]],
 [7, [300.0, 1423.0, 371.0, 1729.0]],
 [8, [1631.0, 1614.0, 2067.0, 1728.0]],
 [9, [304.0, 1810.0, 790.0, 1961.0]],
 [10, [1438.0, 1902.0, 2065.0, 2014.0]],
 [11, [1384.0, 2075.0, 1887.0, 2194.0]],
 [12, [997.0, 2241.0, 1099.0, 2319.0]],
 [13, [1392.0, 2331.0, 2010.0, 2447.0]],
 [14, [999.0, 2341.0, 1100.0, 2419.0]],
 [15, [997.0, 2441.0, 1100.0, 2519.0]],
 [16, [999.0, 2542.0, 1100.0, 2619.0]]]
```

Somehow I need to achieve same result as `desired_list` without using .`sort` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I've solved it and I'm sharing the solution in case anybody bumps into similar situation. I'm sure there are many easier ways though.

```
temporary=[]
dummy_list = [None] * len(list_to_modify)

for x in list_to_modify:
  val = x[0]
  first_cond = val - 20
  second_cond = val + 20
  for y in list_to_modify:
    if list_to_modify.index(y) != 0:
      if y[0]>first_cond and y[0]<second_cond:
        if y in temporary:
          pass
        else:
          temporary.append([list_to_modify.index(y),y])
  #this is where the magic happens
  idx = []
  coords = []

  for x, y in temporary:
    idx.append(x)
    coords.append(y)
  coords.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
  idx.sort()

  merged_list = [(idx[i], coords[i]) for i in range(0, len(idx))] 

  for x in merged_list:
    if x[1] in list_to_modify:
      dummy_list.pop(x[0])
      dummy_list.insert(x[0],x[1])
  temporary.clear()

#I add the first element because I didn't want to touch it.
dummy_list.pop(0)
dummy_list.insert(0, list_to_modify[0])

#dummy list becomes what I want:
 dummy_list=[[296.0, 277.0, 1560.0, 361.0],
 [1964.0, 490.0, 2063.0, 573.0],
 [291.0, 573.0, 371.0, 882.0],
 [1958.0, 595.0, 2059.0, 674.0],
 [1957.0, 696.0, 2058.0, 777.0],
 [1959.0, 797.0, 2060.0, 876.0],
 [298.0, 1084.0, 785.0, 1235.0],
 [300.0, 1423.0, 371.0, 1729.0],
 [1631.0, 1614.0, 2067.0, 1728.0],
 [304.0, 1810.0, 790.0, 1961.0],
 [1438.0, 1902.0, 2065.0, 2014.0],
 [1384.0, 2075.0, 1887.0, 2194.0],
 [997.0, 2241.0, 1099.0, 2319.0],
 [1392.0, 2331.0, 2010.0, 2447.0],
 [999.0, 2341.0, 1100.0, 2419.0],
 [997.0, 2441.0, 1100.0, 2519.0],
 [999.0, 2542.0, 1100.0, 2619.0]]
```